# JavaScript simple copy from input to span

Tags: javascript

I need simple javascript code for this. On html page i have one text input, and when you enter text in that input and click Ok, that text show in span tag, or div

I know how to copy text from one text input to another but i need to show text from first input  in span. This code i use for copying from one text inp. to another but can somebody tell me how to make to copy from first in span tag

```
<input type="text" id="inp1" name="input1">
    <input type="text" id="inp2" name="input2">

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var unos = document.getElementById("inp1");
            var ispis = document.getElementById("inp2");
            ispis.value = unos.value;

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: So you're posting here so someone can just do your work for you? With nothing from your side to prove you actually tried a solution? Or even tried google? Here's a tip. innerHTML

Comment: It'll be exactly the same, except you want to set the `textContent` property of the `<span>` element, rather than `value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ..

```
<span id="testspan">Sometexthere</span>
```

you can get hold of its contents with

```
var spanContent=document.getElementById("testspan").innerHTML;
```

this returns the HTML content of the span including tags.

You can set the content of a span with ...

```
document.getElementById("testspan").innerHTML="SomeContent";
```

This isn't just for spans - it works on any HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="inp1" name="input1" value="5" >
<input type="text" id="inp2" name="input2" value="7">
<p onclick="myFunction()">swap number</p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var unos = document.getElementById("inp1");
        var ispis = document.getElementById("inp2");
        ispis.innerHTML = unos.value;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: yes i know i was doing like this, just my on click function isn't shown in my question :) i need on click to copy text that i write in first input to span tag